# Node webpack dev server failing 'Cannot GET /' in vuejs project

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am getting a super unhelpful message 'Cannot GET /' printed to my browser when I run my node dev server through webpack. I am building a Vuejs application with the following:

- VueJs structured in a way that was dicated by this [Vue Template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) with my node scripts being identical to the default [commands](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/commands.html)
- Webpack config based on [Vue Loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader)
- Routes handled through [Vue Router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router)

I know this is not a great deal to go off but an idea of what is firing this error (Node? Webpack? Vue Router?) it would point me in the right direction and be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

If you're experiencing this with Vite, make sure you ran just `vite` in your `package.json` script, **NOT** `vite preview`

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Comment: BTW to make `vite preview` work you first need to run `vite build`.

Answer (score 8):

I found myself in the same problem. In my case it was related to the use of **Express** with *Vue.js*. So I am leaving my solution in case anyone finds it useful

I added this code for handling the calls to my `index.html` file

```
app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `var path = require('path')` just so it's clear - thanks! this fixed it 

Comment: for anyone misunderstanding this, it needs to go in your server.js (or equivalent, wherever you import express). If you see an error in your browser window, you likely need to import `path` like @user1274820 mentioned. This fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Node is throwing the error and make sure your vue router is configured properly,Cannot GET simply means you have not assigned a view to your url e.g on express we use 
app.use('/', your route)
and on connect we use
app.get or app.post 
All it's saying is there is no content/view assigned to that url.

Comment: I just put the final touches on a pull request. Turns out it was to do with the paths the webpack config template I was working from: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/188

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was an issue with the vuejs webpack template I was working from: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

The build path was being used in the dev server configuration.

Made this pull request to fix the issue: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/188#issuecomment-230968416

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while running my app in dev. Adding this to the devServer of my `webpack.dev.config` file helped:

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

Answer by Jezperp [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1254).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express check that you have this line:

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

And that "static" matches with the folder specified in your vue.config.js

```
outputDir: path.resolve("../Server/static")
```