# Why does Vue router / Webpack dev server shows Cannot GET /path on page refresh now?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-router

### UPDATE:

It turns out it was a bug in the Vue webpack template on Windows, it will be fixed soon

---

### Question:

I've started a new Vue project by installing it with `vue init webpack projectName` and now I keep getting:  `Cannot GET /path` (on localhost) when I refresh a page.

For example, if I go to `/contact` I'll see the page's content, but as soon as I hit refresh I get `Cannot GET /contact`

More than that, you cannot simply type the route in the address bar manually now, you get the same error.

---

- I have `mode: 'history'`
- I see this on localhost (`npm run dev`)

---

It did work properly a few days ago. How do I make it work now?

All the answers on the internet are not useful (well maybe I didn't applied them properly)

---

### index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Contact from '@/components/Contact'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/contact',
      name: 'Contact',
      component: Contact
    }
  ]
})
```

And because of this I cannot make this redirect work now as well:

```
{
  path: '*',
  redirect: '/'
}
```

I get the same error.

So I figured it might be the Vue Webpack's template fault, I've noticed that `webpack.dev.conf.js` is a bit different now and has lines like this now:

```
devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    [...]
```

Which I would assume has something to do with it.

Comment: Because you don't have a server that's forwarding all matching routes to the client side to handle the routing.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sorry I forgot to mention that I see this on localhost, so the problem is with webpack's dev server. I don't know how make it work now as before

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `webpack.dev.conf.js` add `historyApiFallback: true` just above `historyApiFallback: {...}`. There were some changes in the configuration you can find it on github.

**EDIT**:

Try adding `--history-api-fallback` in `package.json` on line  `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --history-api-fallback --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js"` and run `npm install` again. Or try creating new project with that args.

Note the missing `--history-api-fallback` on that line may have caused the issue. Hope this solves your problem. This was the only way I was able to solve my error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though I still get the same result (I restarted `npm run dev`)

Comment: Thanks! So, do we just have to accept this new workaround and do this step every time or it's just a mistake in the Vue webpack template and it shouldn't be like this in dev mode? I've created an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1965) there on vue-router page. Not sure if it was intentional or not, but that will confuse a lot of people

Comment: @Un1 You're welcome. I don't think this was intentional or a bug seems to be effecting only *Windows* systems as far I know. This is the only info I've found from online sources regarding this issue.

Answer (score 11):

for those who have stumbled upon this problem via **VUE CLI 3**, add below code to `vue.config.js` and then re-run `yarn run serve`:

```
module.exports = {

  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
    }
  }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. Turns out if you use Htmlwebpack plugin in dev.config, the html is not automatically written into disk, so you would need a `HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin` and set `alwaysWriteToDisk: true` in HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    title: 'You app',
    alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
}),
new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(),
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming when `mode: "history"` is being used with the Router. I know this is not the exact solution but yeah, if you are looking for some workaround, probably this might help.

**Just remove mode: "history" and your issue will be resolved.**

Answer (score 1):

The official vue-router documentation talks about this issue, and since I use firebase the solution for modifying "rewrites" in firebase.json works for me:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer copied from vue-router documentation:

```
Add this to your firebase.json:

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: While your link may be helpful, it is not an answer in itself. You should include helpful information from the link directly in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @taylorthurlow I included more details

Answer (score 0):

Check there are no inconsistencies with the static folder.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033515/165326

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with vue router history mode and webpack dev server for a while.  turns out I was missing the "base" property in the vue router definition:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: "/user",
    routes: [ ... ]
});
```

my webpack config looks like this:

```
devServer: {
    ...
    historyApiFallback: {
        rewrites: [
            { from: /^\/user/, to: '/user.html' }
        ]
    }
}
```

so now when I go to http://mylocaldev.com/user or http://mylocaldev.com/user/whatever it works the same as production.

Answer (score 0):

I started my local server with

```
npm run serve
```

When I tried to refresh i got:

> cannot GET /PATH

I added in the routes.js:

```
    const routes = [{
...
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
];
```

That helped...